How to efficiently send one UDP datagram to 10000 destinations in Linux?
The real scenario:

A UDP server has 10000 UDP clients which connected via public Internet IPv4 addresses.
The server wants to send one UDP datagram (whose payload size is 1024 in bytes) to the 10000 UDP clients.

Because the 10000 to-be-sent datagrams have the same payload, I want to avoid copying the payload 10000 times.
However, I tested with sendmsg & sendmmsg, and found the payload copy of 10000 times cannot be avoided.
My questions:

How to efficiently send one UDP datagram to 10000 destinations in Linux?

Does XDP help solve this issue?



Take a look at iptables TEE and nftables dup targets. But isn't it more convinient to use multicast?

And more efficient ...

Are those 10000 destinations all on the local subnet, or are they on various subnets within the same organization, or are they distributed throughout the Internet?

@dimich，the IP:ports of the 10000 clients are constantly changing, can TEE & dup work as expected?

@JeremyFriesner, No. All of the 10000 clients are connected to the server via public Internet IPv4 addresses.

Multicast would be much better.

@StephenC, Multicast is not available on the public Internet.

@xmllmx do you plan to use UDP hole-punching to get the UDP packets delivered to those clients?  (otherwise their various NATs/firewalls will likely block the packets by default)

A UDP packet 'whose payload size is 1024 in bytes' is likely to get fragmented and lost on the Internet anyway. The generally accepted UDP payload limit is 534 bytes. Your project isn't really feasible.

You will also find that transmission time dominates copy time. You have to get these datagrams out of your local LAN onto the Internet. The bandwidth for that is orders of magnitude smaller than memory copy bandwidth. And of course the faster you try to send, the more likely you are to get packet loss.

@xmllmx You can manipulate firefall rules programmatically via netlink. However, iptables does it in very inefficient way, nftables does it quite better. XDP might help but you'll need to implement data link, network and transport layers by yourself. I don't think this will gain performance significantly compared to payload copying.
